# Magento 2. RabbitMQ Ack or Reject message

Tags: magento2, rabbit-mq

I'm wondering if it is possible to manually Ack or Reject message from the RabbitMQ within the Magento 2 consumer process? What is the default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take first the case of `vendor/magento/framework-message-queue/Consumer.php` (this is the consumer instance used by most M2 OOTB consumers). Check the method `process()` and from it go to method `getTransactionCallback()`.

Within this method, the class `vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Queue.php` is called when using `acknowledge()` and `reject()` (in their definition you will find as expected the `basic_ack` and `basic_reject`).

In the case of `vendor/magento/framework-message-queue/BatchConsumer.php`, if you go down the line, you will find usages of the `vendor/magento/framework-message-queue/MessageStatusProcessor.php` class with its `acknowledgeMessages()` and `rejectMessages()` which again point back to the `vendor/magento/framework-amqp/Queue.php` as described above.

So in conclusion, Magento already uses both mechanisms, depending on a specific logic. Check the methods mentioned above to get a grasp on when each is used.

Cheers!

Comment: It seems the reject method doesn't work, I'm trying to add `$queue->reject($message); return;` after vendor/magento/module-asynchronous-operations/Model/MassConsumerEnvelopeCallback.php:103, but messages are still ack-ed.

Comment: does the code reach your line at least? maybe you are on a different flow

Comment: yes, the code reaches normally, but reject doesn't seem to work

Comment: uhmm ok, that's weird, really weird. i mean i can't think of a different reason for implementing reject with basic_reject if not for rejecting messages.